# Prove $(n -1) = (n-1)^{n}$ mod n

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Prove $(n -1) = (n-1)^{n}$ mod n

How would one go about doing this?

Comment: What if n = 4? 3^4 = 1 not 3

Comment: why not just accept TonyK's answer? It is a valid/useful answer for the question as stated. Because other users have contributed content, I'm reluctant to delete the question.

Comment: @willie, I have now done so, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

But this is just

$-1 = (-1)^n \mod n$

which is true if and only if $n$ is odd or $n = 2$.